# Obtaining same random events of a dataframe

Tags: python

I just started working with python. I just wished to verify that suppose I pass some .root file to a method which first converts it to dataframe, them shuffles the events in them and gives the output in terms of .h5 format.

```
def loadDF(self, rndm = 12345):

    df = rpd.read_root(self.file_name,self.tree_name)


    rndseed = rndm
    np.random.seed(rndseed)
    index = list(df.index)
    np.random.shuffle(index)

    self.df = df

    hdf = pd.HDFStore(self.tree_name + '.h5')
    hdf.put('hdf', self.df)
    self.hdf = hdf
    hdf.close()
```

And now suppose I want to get the same shuffled dataframe from .root file. All I want is that now .h5 should not be created. Then is the following method correct?

```
def loadDF(self, rndm = 12345):

    ddf = rpd.read_root(self.file_name,self.tree_name)

    rndseed = rndm
    np.random.seed(rndseed)
    index = list(ddf.index)
    np.random.shuffle(index)

    self.ddf = ddf
```

In short, by "np.random.seed(same_number)" could we retrace the same randomized data?

Comment: Try it and find out.  Hard code some number, run it a few times, and see if the output looks the same.  I suspect that it should do, but I haven't played with numpy's random module at all.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95  Sure! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `random.seed` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) in turn reference the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) of the `random.RandomState` class, and here we have the definitive word on your question

> *Compatibility Guarantee* A fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to ‘RandomState’ methods using the same parameters will always produce the same results up to roundoff error except when the values were incorrect. Incorrect values will be fixed and the NumPy version in which the fix was made will be noted in the relevant docstring. Extension of existing parameter ranges and the addition of new parameters is allowed as long the previous behavior remains unchanged.

So, as long as there is not the need to fix a bug in the `RandomState` class or one of its methods, you are guaranteed that your results will be the same.

In my opinion, with reference to your question

> In short, by "np.random.seed(same_number)" could we retrace the same randomized data?

it's not a YES but it's however a yes...